# Update existing SQL Server 2008 table via Flat File using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

**I am trying to update existing records or add any new ones to a SQL Server table using a flat file. Also I need it work as an SSIS package.** I don't get an option to do a source query like I do for Excel, etc. when setting up the import task and even when I was trying to use Excel my options seemed limited to simple selects for the source query.

I really need to be able to run a full script that checks the first column (which is my key), updates existing records, then adds any new ones. Maybe I am taking the wrong approach here altogether, but I thought there was a way to do this with SSIS. Can someone point me in the right direction? **If it were two tables and I didn't have to use SSIS I would just write the sql and be done with it. It's really the bridge with using flat files and SSIS (automating the import) that I'm looking for here.**

Just to give a quick background of what I ultimately am trying to accomplish:
We do exports of our data into flat files and those will go to a ftp server. We then have the customer import from those files into table representations of them so they can report against them.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow either of the below approach :

- Load the entire flatfile into a staging table and then update / insert the records based on the criteria you want. After the process is completed, you can truncate the staging table.
- Look into using [Lookup transform](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/) as described in [Updating Rows in Incremental Loads – Level 4 of the Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/)

Refer to this excellent series : [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) for more details.

Comment: Isn't loading the data one of your first steps in the SSIS package?